# Circular inversion notes or books

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, inversive-geometry

I am preparing a small lesson that I have to do about geometry. The topic of the lesson is circular inversion. Can you suggest me some sources where I can find some nice material about it?
Thanks!!

Comment: Have a look at Lockwood's *A Book of Curves*.

Comment: [Brannan & al's book "Geometry"](http://www.gimnazija-izdijankoveckoga-kc.skole.hr/upload/gimnazija-izdijankoveckoga-kc/multistatic/817/Brannan_D.A.,_Esplen_M.F.,_Gray_J.J._Geometry_(draft,_2ed.,_CUP,_2012)(ISBN_1107647835)(O)(603s)_MD_(1).pdf) is nice.